# officeapps embedding excel file not working

Tags: excel, embed

I have some project where i have to embed excel sheet in a web page

i am using micrrosoft online viewer for this

```
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://example.com/docs/some.xlsx
```

this is working fine

but if my url has any port this is showing error

```
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://example.com:8282/docs/some.xlsx
/*this is showing error*/
```

Error is

> An error occurred
>   We're sorry, but for some reason we can't open this for you.

how can i embed excel online with url having ports

Comment: [TechNet article about planning Office Web Apps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/plan-office-web-apps-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
Using Ports **80 (HTTP), 443 (HTTPS) and 809 (traffic between WAC farm servers)**
I'm not certain, but I'm not sure you can route for officeapps to alternate ports.